# jQuery Tools scrollable + mobile safari bug?

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, jquery-tools, scrollable

The jQuery Tools Scrollable on this page...

https://s140452.gridserver.com/

does not switch images in iPad or iPhone... is there a bug, or something that I'm doing wrong?

```
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('.scrollable').scrollable({
            circular: true
        }).navigator('#slide-nav').autoscroll({ autoplay: true });
    });
```

Comment: Being familiar with the shortcomings of jQuery Tools, I'd say it's a problem with jQuery Tools... IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use scrollable if you want your slider to work well on iOS / mobile safari.

http://iosscripts.com/iosslider-jquery-horizontal-slider-for-iphone-ipad-safari/

that script is where it's at.